# vbscript called from batch file from task scheduler failing to open excel workbook

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a vbscript that I'm calling from a batch file. Inside this script it opens an excel file on a sharepoint site. When I run this batch file by dbl clicking it everything works. When I run from the task scheduler the log file shows it's failing to open the excel file on the line:

```
XL.Workbooks.Open(wrkbook)
```

Note that it works fine when dbl clicked. I'm guessing it's some kind of permissions or something but not sure who/what/when/where/why. Any ideas?

When I pipe the vbscript error I get:

Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'file path here' for one of the following reason:

- The file name or path does not exist (but it does)
- The file is being used by another program (it's not as I can open the file)
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook (not sure what this is really saying but doesn't seem to apply either)

Comment: Check the user that is configured to run this specific scheduled task. You need to use one that has access to the Sharepoint site.

Comment: It does. I'm logged into the server I'm doing this on as that user that I have running this task and I can get to the file and open it both manually and through dbl clicking the batch file. Updating answer as I piped the vbscript error to file and it for sure seems to be some kind of access error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, you have GOT to be kidding me. The answer is a handful of posts below in this thread and you'll never believe it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac2549f5-fc1e-494d-9015-70cb31d3aeb2/opening-excel-workbook-fails-when-run-from-scheduled-task-on-windows-server-2008-rw?forum=exceldev

Literally, and I'm not joking here, all I had to do was create a a folder named 'desktop' in C:\windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile. So the final path is 'C:\windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\desktop'.

Can you believe that? That's insane.